# Irreducibility of smooth representations and Hecke modules

Tags: representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $(\pi, V)$ a (smooth) admissible representation of a locally profinite topological group $G$ and fix $K \le G$ an open compact subgroup. [These](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Edprasad/ictp2.pdf) notes claim that if $V^K$ is a nonzero irreducible module for the Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_K := C^\infty_{c}(K\backslash G/K)$, then $V$ is irreducible.

Surely this is not true as written? Since we have an equivalence of categories between smooth $G$-reps and nondegenerate $\mathcal{H} = \varinjlim_K \mathcal{H}_K$-modules, it is certainly true that if $V^K$ is $\mathcal{H}_K$-irreducible for *all* $K$, then $V$ is irreducible, but the necessity of considering all $K$ seems certain to me.

Comment: Maybe also assuming that $V$ is generated by $V^K$, and the dual $V^*$ is generated by $(V^*)^K$?

Comment: I can see why the first condition might be helpful, but why the second? An argument involving matrix characters or something?

Comment: Even if $V^K$ generates $V$, $V$ can fail to be irreducible. But if the dual behaves similarly, then we do have irreducibility.